# ExpressionTree - GetSetMethod Error: Method 'System.String get_Name()' is not defined for type 'System.String'

Tags: c#, reflection, lambda, expression-trees

Here is my method:

```
    public static MethodCallExpression ClonePropertyAssignmentLambda<T>(Expression source, string property)
    {
        var targetExp = Expression.Parameter(typeof (T), "target");
        var propertyInfo = typeof (T).GetProperty(property);
        var targetProperty = Expression.Property(targetExp, propertyInfo);
        var sourceProperty = Expression.Property(source, propertyInfo);

        return Expression.Call(targetProperty, ((PropertyInfo) targetProperty.Member).GetSetMethod(), sourceProperty);
    }
```

Here is how I'm calling it:

```
ClonePropertyAssignmentLambda<Person>(source, "Name")
```

I'm getting the error on the Expression.Call line.  I get a similar error if I call GetGetMethod.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to get the `Name` property of a `string` object.

Change it to

```
return Expression.Call(targetExp, propertyInfo.GetSetMethod(), sourceProperty);
```

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I figured it out like 2 seconds after posting.  Why do I always do that?

The first param for Expression.Call should be targetExp.

Comment: Because when you explain things to others, they become clear to you :-) If you didn't write the post, you might have spent much more time figuring things out.